# Generate files with multiple columns and compute spacing with Xtend

Tags: templates, xtend

How can I generate columns with spacing using xtend? Is there a way, without computing by myself the length of the columns? Are there any utility classes for generating columns?

The generated output, that I want to achieve is:

```
{ AA, -1, XX, FFXXXYY, 0, 0, 0 },
{ BB,  1, FF,       1, 0, 0, "Blup" },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no Xtend specific utilities, but you may want to use Guava's `Strings.padStart` to prepend the spaces per column.

Comment: It works great with xtend.  I used import static extension com.google.common.base.Strings.* and then object.name.startPad(10,' '). Thanks for your answer!